# Finding radio button selection with idtabs jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm using the following html along with the idTabs jquery plugin to create a tabbed signup/login/anonymous post form.

```
 <div id="form_tabs">
        <ul>
          <li id="tab_radio_1"><span class="corner_fix"></span><input class="input_radio" type="radio" name="registered" value="1" checked="checked" /> <a class="selected" href="#tab1">Yep, I'm new here</a></li>
          <li id="tab_radio_2"><input class="input_radio" type="radio" name="registered" value="2" /> <a href="#tab2">Nope, I'm registered</a></li>
          <li id="tab_radio_3"><input class="input_radio" type="radio" name="registered" value="3" /> <a href="#tab3">I don't want to register</a></li>
        </ul>
 //more divs, radio buttons and text boxes below//
```

The problem is that if I click on the href link to change the tab (and subsequently change the selected radio button) it doesn't seem to fire an event that value of the radio button has changed.

I need to find out which radio button is currently selected, and so far none of the 'normal' Jquery code for finding this out has worked.

Help very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

one way would be like

```
$("#form_tabs ul li a").on('click',function(e){
 if($(this).closest("li> :radio").is(':checked'))
  console.log('im checked');
 else
   console.log('im NOT checked');
});
```